# Using link_to with i18n and glyphicon, Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby, internationalization

I cant figure out how to use the link_to correctly with both internationalization tags and a glyphicon.

My code currently looks like this.

```
<%=link_to t('health_info.twitter_posts_featuredacc')+' <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>'.html_safe, health_info_tweets_path(type: 'featured') %>
```

It pulls the correct translation but it also shows everything in the ''.html_safe as normal html code and not as the glyphicon.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the block syntax for this:

```
<%= link_to(health_info_tweets_path(type: 'featured')) do %>
  <%= t('health_info.twitter_posts_featuredacc') %>
  <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I was about to but I couldn´t do that within the first 5 minuts of the answer. You answered too quickly. :) Upvote and accept has been done. Thanks again.